# Kotlin Coroutine doesn't execute multiple suspend functions

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I have a simple sequence of suspend functions (in Android Kotlin) which I want to run in sequence (once first is finished, then run second.)

I tried doing something which seamed reasonable like this:

```
class SomeService {

    init {

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            firstSuspendFunction()
            secondSuspendFunction()
        }
    }

}
```

However, only first one is run, second is never executed. Why is that so?

Edit:
I tried to rule out some possible issues, and what seemed to worked was by completely emptying first function (empty body)!

The problem is that my firstFunction actually works, it has something like this:

```
private suspend fun firstSuspendFunction() {
    localProtoDataStore.preferences.collect {
        someDataList.addAll(it.preferenceData)
    }
}
```

Could it be that somehow `launch` never knowns if first suspend function has finished?

Comment: Are you sure that firstSuspendFunction() does not throw an Exception? This would cancel the coroutine and secondSuspendFunction() wouldn't be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not see any errors in the logs. How can I prove/debug this is the case?

Comment: I've added an edit, does it give more context?

Comment: Please provide the code for "secondSuspendFunction()".

Comment: Easiest way would be wrapping firstSuspendFunction in a try-catch. If secondSuspendFunction is executed now that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: Your code is correct.  Something must be going wrong with `firstSuspendFunction()`.  (It could also be running forever instead of failing -- e.g. if your flow doesn't terminate.)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm still not understanding the technical reason why it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `localProtoDataStore.preferences` returns a `Flow` and it seems infinite, because it listens to the preferences changes. Calling `collect()` on such `Flow` will suspend any function until the collection is finished (but it never finished because the `Flow` is infinite) or `CoroutineScope`, which executed a coroutine, is canceled.

So to execute the second function you have a couple of options. For example you can get only one value from the `Flow`:

```
private suspend fun firstSuspendFunction() {
    localProtoDataStore.preferences.firstOrNull {
        someDataList.addAll(it.preferenceData)
    }
}
```

Or you can get rid of using `Flow` in the `firstSuspendFunction()` and just retrieve a current data in preferences:

```
private suspend fun firstSuspendFunction() {
    val data = localProtoDataStore.preferences.get() // I don't know the exact name of the function, but the idea is clear
    someDataList.addAll(data)
}
```

Or you can just launch another coroutine to collect data from the `Flow`:

```
scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    launch {
        firstSuspendFunction()
    }
    secondSuspendFunction()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Launch new **Coroutine** for each function call inside parent coroutine so that they can collect data from Flow individually without falling under *suspension of parent coroutine*. For example, in your case:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    launch { 
        firstSuspendFunction()
    }
    launch { 
        secondSuspendFunction()
    }
    ....
}
```